# How to get the stock music player to play WMA files?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, nexus-one, music-player, wma

I'm using android 2.2 on a stock Nexus one (from the pre-developer phone stage). Should the music player be able to cope with WMAs? I'm sure I've seen references to it coping with them, but they are currently just dead weight on the SD card.

I actually quite like the stock player so installing a new player is the fallback option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having been reminded I asked this question, I did a bit of digging and it seems that this is a feature of the nexus one and really something I should have known (or found quicker than I did).

Spec is at: http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_google_nexus_one-3069.php

Includes the line: - MP3/eAAC+/WAV music player

...which notedly excludes wma.

As others have suggested, this is nexus one specific and will require extra software to solve.

Answer (score 2):

The stock music player on my EVO plays .wma tracks, but it does not read any of the meta data (track number, artist etc.)

I have tried several music apps and none of them correctly read this meta data.  [Music Player Pro](http://www.android.com/market/#app=com.tbig.playerpro) is vastly superior to any of the others and is well worth the cost.

Comment: Thanks. Guessing the phone is lacking the right drivers. Really don't want to have to re-rip all my CDs. If you don't mind will leave question open.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have WMA support when I first got my HTC Desire Z, and from the looks of things on the net, HTC Sense provides (/provided?) WMA support itself - explaining the lack of love for the format on the Nexus One. I have since rooted and lost this on Cyanogenmod, first with the system failing to read Artist tags but still playing in the stock player, and now failing to play at all.

I would suggest [PowerAmp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer) as a temporary workaround as this does recognise WMAs and is, generally, quite a good player. I didn't fancy paying after the free trial, however, so have started re-ripping my music into MP3 format.

The Android library will not index WMA files, but any app that builds its own library of tracks should suffice (Museek used to, before becoming [JukeFox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.ethz.dcg.pancho2)).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as well with the [stock music](http://audiomicro.com) player.  I tried this one instead --> 
http://www.mixzing.com/  and it resolved my issue.

Comment: Mixzing may fix the tag problem, but unfortunately it relies on built in codevs so it can't play wmas on the Nexus one.